# Replace HTML element with same id value

Tags: css

I am learning CSS recently and got across this requirement in my project. My HTML looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="lvl1_nav">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="leftheaderlogo" style="height: 25px !important;"
                        class="logoPadding" rowspan="2"></td>
                    <td width="25%"><span id="lvl1_nav_title"
                        style="font-weight: normal;">PRODUCT TITLE</span></td>
                    <td rowspan="2" width="75%">...</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="25%"><span id="lvl1_nav_title"
                        style="cursor: default; font-weight: bold;">PRODUCT 2nd
                            Level Title</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <select id="portalModuleGroups" class="modulemenu"
            style="display: none;">
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont have any option to use any other techniques other than CSS due to code limitations.

I am looking for the best options to replace the **"PRODUCT TITLE"** and **"PRODUCT 2nd Level Title"** using CSS. The main problem I am facing is, both the span's are having same id **span id="lvl1_nav_title"**.

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean replace? You want to replace the content or apply CSS on both spans?

Comment: *"The main problem i am facing is, both the span's are having same id"* -- solve that first. `id`s should be unique.

Comment: It is not dynamic way.

Comment: You can't use IDs more than once on a page...so thats the start of the issue.

Comment: Also...tables for layout? Time to come into *this* century.

Comment: It is not valid to have an id twice in your HTML

Comment: just use class. in css use `.lvl1_nav_title{...}`

Comment: do you mean replace the content or the positioning?

Comment: I agree with all above comments. But unfortunately i dont have control on that code. Its is coming from some existing application. We are showing that as part of a portlet in our app. So we are trying to replace those content of those SPANs dynamically and we have to use CSS due to limitations.

Comment: Sherali, if we do this way, then it will replace both the string with same value, correct? I want to assign different strings to each one of them.

Comment: So, you can't replace span id to class?.

Comment: use. `#lvl1_nav  td[with^=25]:first-child span{...}` and `#lvl1_nav  td[with^=25]:nth-child(2) span{...}` it not correct way

Comment: OR, use. #lvl1_nav #lvl1_nav_title:first-child span{...} and #lvl1_nav #lvl1_nav_title:nth-child(2) span{...} it not dynamic way. But, if you can't change ids it is one way

Comment: what should i put inside the span{...}. Sorry for asking the basic. I am not used to CSS coding. Do i have to use content: XXX in first span and content: YYY in 2nd span{}?

Answer (score 2):

#### Duplicate ID issue

Several others have pointed out the issue of the duplicate IDs. Yes, that makes your HTML non-conformant. Yes, bad things could happen. However, in practice it will work OK:

```
#lvl1_nav_title { color: purple; }
```

will apply the color to all the elements with that ID.

If it's possible to write JS, but for some reason not possible to change the multiple IDs, although you cannot address both elements with

```
document.getElementById('lvl1_nav_title')
```

because that just returns one element, you can address them with

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id=lvl1_nav_title]')
```

#### Cannot change HTML content with CSS

The basic roadblock you face is that you cannot change HTML content via CSS. Bottom line, you cannot do what you want without JS.

Therefore, at the end of the day, you really need to fix your HTML to have unique IDs, and in any case you'll have to use JS to replace text within the elements.

#### The ultimate hack with CSS

This is **not** recommended unless you absolutely, positively cannot touch the HTML or write JSS and **must** have a CSS-only solution.

The idea is to move the element way off to the edge of the screen, where it will be hidden. Then, apply an `::after` pseudo-element providing the new text, positioned so it will be back where the the original element was supposed to be originally.

CSS:

```
span {    
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
}

span::before {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 9999px;
}

span:first-child::before { content: 'NEW PRODUCT TITLE'; }
span:last-child::before  { content: 'NEW 2nd LEVEL TITLE'; }
```

HTML:

```
<span id="lvl1_nav_title">PRODUCT TITLE</span>
<span id="lvl1_nav_title">PRODUCT 2nd Level Title</span>
```

Obviously, you will have to adjust things to work with your specific HTML structure, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you toraz. I will work on it. Sorry for my delayed response. Seems promising. Thanks all for your inputs.